# Can we build large scale application generated by hyperledger composer generator?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have generated a angular app using hyperledger composer generator and now i want to assure that is it suitable for building large scale application?

Answer (score 0):

The Hyperledger Composer Angular Generator is used to generate an example web application from a provided business network archive (.bna) or running business network. For the business network in question, it discovers the defined business network schema (eg. assets participants and list of transaction classes) and produces a skeleton Angular application which interfaces/can connect with a Composer REST server. Building 'large scale application(s) usually requires an app design & architectural approach (scaling, capacity, zones, recovery etc etc).

The main purpose of the generator is to provide a sample web application which allows developers to understand how their business network can become a complete application.

The generator is a useful tool because it provides a functioning use case with a business network as a basis to demonstrate interaction to the blockchain to interested parties. There are plenty of [resources](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/6-best-practices-pro-tips-for-angular-cli-better-developer-experience-7b328bc9db81) out on Google to help you depending on what approach you wish to take from an Angular app design perspective.